# Android: Toolbar and Status Bars Configuration Issues

Tags: xml, android-layout, label, toolbar, android-statusbar

My application has issues in particular with the Toolbar and Status bars behaving improperly. I want my Toolbar and Status bar to be the same color to blend seamlessly. Also, I would like the activity title to be displayed on the label for all activities. For some activities this works fine. For example, the main activity: 
[image]

However, all activities except the Main Activity refuse to display the Label and only the Main Activity and Representatives Activity show the correct color configuration. For example, the Representatives toolbar has the correct color combination, but does not have the label. 
[image]

Other Activities niether have the correct color combination or label like the Single Representative Activity

[image]

Here is my Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.gabe.politicianspulse">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".VoterInformation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_voter_information"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Representatives"
        android:label="Representatives"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity android:name=".SingleRepresentative"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_single_representative"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        />

    <activity android:name=".Elections"
        android:label="@string/elections"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        />

    <activity android:name=".SingleElection"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText"
        android:label="@string/elections"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
       >


    </activity>

</application>
```

Toolbar Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:titleTextColor="#ffffff">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#2F3C4B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#CC4848</color>
</resources>
```

I can deliver any Java or XML code from any of the activities upon request. Thanks for the help!
-Gabe

Comment: Do your Activties extend `AppCompatAcitivity`? Is there any setup of the Toolbar within your Activity code?

Comment: Yes, my classes extend AppCompatActivity.  To set up the toolbar, I write some xml code in the layout file. <include layout="@layout/toolbar_main"

Answer (score 0):

There might be some code missing. Try this:

Inside the `onCreate` of all Activities that include the ToolBar, add the following code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```